# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" when loading module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

i wanted to move part of my code into JS module, but when I did that i get:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` on line 3 of script.js

The **script.js** starts like this:

```
'use strict'

import {MyClass} from "./module.js";
```

The **module.js** starts like this:

```
'use strict';

export class MyClass {
```

Both files are imported in **index.html** at the end of body:

```
<script src="js/module.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

When I change reference to **script.js** to `type="module"`, the error is not thrown anymore, but I cannot use any of script.js's functions in onload etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers support ES6 modules as long as you use `type="module"` in your imports. So you need to make it like this:

```
<script src="js/script.js" type="module"></script>
```

Now you said that you cannot use functions from script.js when you do this. could you be more specific ? (by sharing code and error may be)

Comment: In **script.js**, there is function *processFile()* which i use to process file input. I use:

    <input type="file" id="files" onchange="processFile()">

And it throws me function not found.

Comment: can you share your html and typescript code ? it could help see better :) !

Comment: Sorry I know this is not the answer, but I am having the same issue, this seems to be what is happening but I cannot seem to get an onload event to take a module funtion either. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630310/use-functions-defined-in-es6-module-directly-in-html