# Is it possible to use onclick functions from a module without using either global functions or query Selectors?

Tags: javascript, html, import, module, export

From research, I have found that the two main methods to use on click events from modules are either to use global variables via the window object or to use query Selectors from within the javascript module. Here is a much reduced and simplified version of the code I am working on:

---

### index.html

```
<div id="list">
  <p id="text">Random Text</p>
  <ul>
    <li onclick="replaceText('Option A')">Option A</li>
    <li onclick="replaceText('Option B')">Option B</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button onclick="replaceList()""> <h1>Press me</h1>
```

---

### user_interaction.js

```
import { functionB, functionA } from "./functions.js"; 
export function replaceText(name) {
  let currentText = "";
  currentText = name;
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = name;
}

export function replaceList() {
  if (currentText === "Option A") {
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = functionA("Option A");
  }
  if (currentText === "Option B") {
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = functionA("Option B");
  }
}
```

---

The issue I am facing is that: I need to import function A and function B from a separate file, but to do this - I must first convert my user interaction file into a module. But, by converting my code into a module - this causes the on click events to return

```
 "Uncaught ReferenceError function is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"
```

when I try to import from user interaction. From research, I can tell that this is because imports from modules have their own scope and thus the function is not defined.

I would like to solve this issue with a method that does not use a query selector or a global function as I have been told that global functions are not best practice. The reason I would prefer to not use a query selector is that I would like (if possible) to see that there is an on click event handler on the tags instead of having no indicator in the html tag.

Just in case, I'd like to clarify a few things. I am aware of the two methods described in these links, however, I am asking whether it's possible to approach the issue from a different route - one that preferably keeps on click in the html tags without resorting to global functions or query selectors in javascript. Additionally, I would like to clarify that this code has been dramatically simplified so that I can clearly focus on the concept of the question.

Here are some sources from which I have conducted my research:

---

Unfortunately stackoverflow keeps viewing the links as improperly formatted code so will have to write them in a code block:

- [Stack Overflow page about undefined functions after importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590393/es6-modules-undefined-onclick-function-after-import)
- [Stack Overflow page with similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630310/use-functions-defined-in-es6-module-directly-in-html)
- [Forum Post about same issue](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-javascript-maps-sdk-questions/how-to-call-module-function-on-button-click-event/td-p/579181)
- [Youtube Link regarding HTML Button Element errors with onclick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvdtjhedmgo)

Comment: Setting `.innerHTML` is absolutely not the way to attach event handlers. It's hard to understand what you're trying to do, but you might want to google `addEventListener`

Comment: @Pointy thank you for this comment, I am a self-taught programmer so it is hard for me to know what is 'best practice' as I get most of my information from online videos and websites. I will look into addEventListener - thank you again for the suggestion.

Comment: You don't need to use "import { functionB, functionA } from "./functions.js"; "
You can use a simpler method that works better 
**indeks.html**
`<div id="list">
    <p id="text">Random Text</p>
    <ul>
      <li onclick="replaceText('Option A')">Option A</li>
      <li onclick="replaceText('Option B')">Option B</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button onclick="replaceList()""> <h1>Press me</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./user_interaction.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./functions.js"></script>`

Comment: @Krull this wouldn't work for me as: functions.js was designed as a module and as such it's functions all have the export keyword before them, thus causing issues when it is read in the html file? I'll have to try it out to double check though - I'll try it out although my real code is a lot more complex so it may take some time

Comment: "*one that preferably keeps on click in the html tags*" - why? [Separate these concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_content_and_presentation). Use selectors. They don't have to be global.