# Uncaught ReferenceError:

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Hi i have this JavaScript Code. But i get the error: **`"Uncaught ReferenceError: saveMarker is not defined"`** from the console when i click the "save" button. I call the code below from my "main" HTML file with a script block. The Popup is functioning but when i klick on save the error comes up.

I use it with the leaflet library which is referenced by the "L" if someone is wondering. I also added a picture of the project.

I Tried this Version:

```
export function markerpopup(map, latlng) {
    console.log("starte markerpopup");
    var actual_location = "";
    var popupContent = `
      <button onclick="saveMarker()">Speichern</button>`;
    L.popup()
        .setLatLng(latlng)
        .setContent(popupContent)
        .openOn(map);
}

function saveMarker() {
    console.log("starte saveMarker");
}
```

And this Version (Which should be the same as https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/event_onclick.asp):

```
export function markerpopup(map, latlng) {
    console.log("starte markerpopup");
    var actual_location = "";

   var popupContent = `
            <button onclick="saveMarker()">Speichern</button>

            <script> 
                function saveMarker() {
                    console.log("starte saveMarker");
                }
            </script>`;

    L.popup()
        .setLatLng(latlng)
        .setContent(popupContent)
        .openOn(map);
}
```

Would appreciate if someone could help!

Tried different places to place the `saveMarker` function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use functions defined in ES6 module directly in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630310/use-functions-defined-in-es6-module-directly-in-html)

Comment: Hi Thank you for the Answer! It looks like kind of a similar Problem but i have the function in the same .js file not in a different one like in the example. Which makes it for me even more weird why it cant find the function. I tried to import save marker as an export function from a differentt file like the example but its still the same error.

Comment: You call a function from html. It doesn't matter where the element has been created. `window.saveMarker = saveMarker`

Comment: Do yourself a favor and stay as far away from W3Schools as possible. It is well-known to have outdated, incomplete, or just plain incorrect information. Use the [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/) as they are recognized as an authoritative resource.

Comment: Thank for your Responses, i will stay away from this site! I Solved the error with the solution from 3limin4t0r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing a string to [`setContent()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#divoverlay-setcontent) you could pass an [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement).

You can create one by calling [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), then attach the event handler with [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and set the content with [`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append), [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), or any other method to update the contents of an `HTMLElement`.

```js
export function markerpopup(map, latlng) {
    console.log("starte markerpopup");

    var actual_location = "";

    const popupContent = document.createElement("button");
    popupContent.addEventListener("click", saveMarker);
    popupContent.append("Speichern");
    // or if you want a more complex structure without manually building all elements
    // popupContent.innerHTML = `<span>Speichern</span>`;

    L.popup()
        .setLatLng(latlng)
        .setContent(popupContent)
        .openOn(map);
}

function saveMarker() {
    console.log("starte saveMarker");
}
```

Comment: This one has done it! Thank you very much. Is this a "Javascript button/popup" which calss the HTML popup?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you're asking, but let me say this: Whenever you set `popupContent` to `\`<button onclick="saveMarker()">Speichern</button>\`` the browser will parse the HTML, and create the DOM structure for you. All we do here is manually create the structure, and pass it to `setContent()`. The reason the *click* event works is because `saveMarker` is available in the current context. Yet if you pass an HTML string `onclick="saveMarker()"` will be called in the global context, not in the context of the current module, causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `export` syntax, I assume that you are using an es6 module
, and a `<script type="module">` tag. if this is true, then your function declaration is scoped in the module, and not the whole page. You need to do something like this:

```js
    //set the button id for yourself
    //this is just a placeholder
    document.querySelector('#popupbutton').onclick = saveMarker
    
    function saveMarker() {
        console.log("started saveMarker");
    }
```

Comment: a globally polluted version gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

what you can try to do is

```
function markerpopup(map, latlng) {
    console.log("starte markerpopup");

    var actual_location = "";

    var popupContent = `

            <button id="savemarkerId" >Speichern</button>
              
    `;

    const saveMarker = () => {
        console.log("started saveMarker");
    }


    L.popup()
        .setLatLng(latlng)
        .setContent(popupContent)
        .openOn(map);

    document.querySelector('#savemarkerId').onclick = saveMarker

}
```

or you can try

```
    function markerpopup(map, latlng) {
        console.log("starte markerpopup");
    
        var actual_location = "";
    
var button = document.createElement('button');

button.innerHTML = 'click me';
button.onclick = function()
{
    alert("hello, world");
}

        L.popup()
            .setLatLng(latlng)
            .setContent(button)
            .openOn(map);
    
    
    }
```