# How to call one function defined in a javascript to another javascript file?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I am trying to import one function declared in a javascript file into another javascript file, but can't get it right. I am not using any transpiler.

I am trying to import variables and functions from one JavaScript file to another but don't want to use Transpilers. I can't get it right how to import and export functions. I am using `Adobe{Brackets}` as my IDE.

I have already converted the importing script to a module, but still I am
unable to export or import. As a second try, I tried converting exporting script
to a module but still get the following error:

> Parsing Error- Export and import keyword are reserved.

As a third try, I converted both files to a module. Still it does not work.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head><title>Test1</title>
</head>
<body>
<button type = "button" class= "slctbtn" onclick= "select()" id= "selct_btn">Select</button>
</body>
<script src="javascript/select.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="javascript/Test.js"></script>
</html>
```

**javascript/Test.js:**

```
var today = 28;
export {today};
```

**javascript/select.js:**

```
import {today} from "./javascript/Test.js";
function select(){
    var month = "august";
    var year = "2019";
    alert("this is " + month + " of the year " + year + " and today is " + today + " day.");
}
```

**Expected Result:**
[Alert must show text like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES6FZ.png)

Comment: The from part of the import is relative to the location of the importing file.

Comment: Your `select.js` script tag is missing the `type="module"`. You can only import and export in module scripts.

Comment: I put all javascript.js files in a folder named as javascript thus location of it must be javascript/Test.js. But i tried {./Test } also as well as i tried converting both the files as modules. Still got Parsing error

Comment: See also [Accessing exported functions from html file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50176213/1048572) and [ES6 Modules: Undefined onclick function after import](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44590393/1048572) or [Use functions defined in ES6 module directly in html](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53630310/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really mix and match `module` and non-module JS. So:

- Use only **one** `<script>` element

  - Make it `type="module"`
  - Load `select.js` with it
- Use `import {today} from "./Test.js";` because the path is relative to the JS
- Since variables in modules are not global, use `addEventListener` inside `select.js` and **not** an `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import {today} from "./Test.js";
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `import {today} from "./javascript/Test.js";`

with `import {today} from "./Test";`;

Here is working demo https://stackblitz.com/fork/react?file=index.js

Comment: That will be necessary to get the code working, but it isn't the source of the error: trying to `import` in a regular js script is. Needs `type="module"`.