# Learning how to use ES6 import and modules getting Reference Error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module, es6-modules

I am just beginning to learn ES6 imports, with the hopes to transition an application to modular ES6. My current project has the following directory structure:

```
index.html
-scripts\
   --function1.js
   --function2.js
   --globals.js
   --main.js
```

My index.html file code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Modular JS Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="changevar1()">Change Var 1</button>
  <button onclick="changevar2()">Change Var 2</button>
  <script src="scripts/main.js" type="module"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I have two buttons which have `onclick` triggers assigned to them. These functions namely, `changevar1()` and `changevar2()` are found in files `function1.js` and `function2.js` respectively. And my entry point is `main.js`.

My main.js is as follows:

```
import {globalvar1 as globalvar1,
  globalvar2 as globalvar2} from "./globals.js";
import {changevar1 as changevar1} from "./function1.js";
import {changevar2 as changevar2} from "./function2.js";

console.log(globalvar1, globalvar2,changevar1,changevar2);
```

My globals.js is where I declare some global variables which will be used by functions in either `functions1.js` or `functions2.js` and is as follows:

```
export let globalvar1 = "I am globalvar1";
export let globalvar2 = "I am globalvar2";
```

My function1.js has the function for the first button and is as follows:

```
import { globalvar1 } from "./globals.js" //do I need to import here?

export function changevar1() {
  globalvar1 = "Now changed globalvar1"
  console.log(globalvar1);
}
```

In the case above, I am importing the `globalvar1` from `globals.js` and I am not sure if that is required, or if it will all come together in `main.js`?

My function2.js has the function for the second button and is as follows:

```
export function changevar2() {
  globalvar2 = "Now changed globalvar2"
  console.log(globalvar2);
}
```

In this case, I was not importing the `globalvar2`, just to see if it was not required.

Now the question is simply when you press the button how can you trigger either `changevar1()` or `changevar2()` to change the `globalvar1` or `globalvar2`? I keep getting "Reference errors".

I have read several online documents and watched a few video tutorials online too to try to understand modular js.
Please excuse my lack of knowledge about modules and any help even if very basic knowledge is helpful.

Comment: You cannot use es6 module directly on the browser you need to have a compiler that converts your es6 code into es5 like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) 
So you need to have a node server which converts you js file into a bundle. Most of the Frameworks like React , Angular follow this process

Comment: My understanding was ES6 modules are compatible in latest version of Chrome and Firefox as per MDN at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility, showing that it has been available for several versions now?

Comment: are the console logs printing the functions and can you directly call the functions from the console to see that are they available in the global scope?

Comment: The `console.log` in main.js shows everything gets imported. However, if you open up a console and try to type in the imports for e.g. `changevar1()` it gives you a reference error.

Comment: @DibakarHalder That is quite outdated, you can use modules in modern browsers just fine.

Comment: Issue 1: your functions are module-scoped, you cannot access them from inline `onclick` attribute event handlers. Instead, use DOM methods to install your click event listeners. Issue 2: you cannot assign to imported variables, they are read-only. You would need to declare your functions in the same file as the variables, where they can assign the local variables (regardless of the fact they are exported).

Comment: I read this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590393/es6-modules-undefined-onclick-function-after-import) which suggests to either (1) expose the function/var as `window.functionname` or (2) use `addEventListener`. In case of (1) is it ok to do so provided you use a namespace like your application name if it is pretty discrete for e.g. `window.DiscreteAppName.functionname`? Or is that considered bad practice?

Comment: Any suggestions on the last comment?