# Import a javascript file and call the function within it

Tags: javascript

I have this file: a.js

```
export function work(){
    // do stuff
}
```

And this jsp file:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/javascripts/a.js"/>'></script>
...
```

How do I call the function "work" from my jsp file? It always says "work is not defined"

Attempted (deeper in the jsp):

```
...
    <th><a href="#" onclick="return work();" > Work # </a></th>
...
```

Comment: Have you tried `"return window.work();"`? Since the script is in the HEAD, the DOM may not be initialized yet. You may need to listen for `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: `href="#"` — if you're linking to the top of the page then you probably shouldn't be using a link and should be using a `<button>` instead.

Comment: This might help if you still want to use modules. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590393/es6-modules-undefined-onclick-function-after-impor

Answer (score 2):

`export` is only supported in ES6 modules, and you aren't loading the JS file as a module.

Remove the `export` keyword.

(If you were loading it as a module `<script src="..." type="module"></script>` then `work` wouldn't be a global so you couldn't call it from an `on*` attribute anyway).

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to **`export`** the function if you linking the file then remove the `return` and the `href` and replce the  with a `button` it's better:

```
<th><<button onclick="work();" > Work # </button></th>
```