# Cannot assign functions to "onclick" from imported class without anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

I have two js files: index.js and TaskList.js (in which I created class "TaskList" then export to index.js).

I want to assign method "sortTaskAsc()" of class "TaskList" to event "onclick" on a button.
So in index.js, when I write like this with anonymous function, it works:

```
getElementByID("btn-sortDown").onclick = () => {taskList.sortTaskAsc()}
```

but when I want to try this way, it doesn't work any more:

```
getElementByID("btn-sortDown").onclick = taskList.sortTaskAsc
```

I notice that when I use the second way for the functions inside index.js, they all work. But when I use with functions from an imported class, they won't.
In console tab it says some error about "undefined".

Please help me understand the reason for this. Thank you guys.

Comment: Maybe because you cannot bind a method of an object as a callback (event) function?

Comment: Could you show us the `undefined` error you are getting?

Comment: becuase `this` changes

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590393/es6-modules-undefined-onclick-function-after-import ?

Comment: You have misspelled `getEleElementByID` in the second try. Maybe that is the reason?

Comment: Thanks Udara for reminding. But actually I didn't mispell in my actual code. Just a mistake when typing this question.

Answer (score 0):

Method sortTaskAsc of TaskList is binded with relevant element because of you use "function" statement.

```
class TaskList {
    sortTaskAsc() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}

let taskList = new TaskList();

getElementByID("btn-sortDown").onclick = taskList.sortTaskAsc
//onclick binds the function with element btn-sortDown. `this` gives an element.

getElementByID("btn-sortDown").onclick = () => taskList.sortTaskAsc()
//Arrow functions are not binded with anything.
//Therefore `this` doesn't be corrupted and it gives the class.
```