# NodeJS importing a local Module

Tags: node.js, module

I have a typescript file of a module I created

```
export function hello() {
  console.log('hello');
}

export function bye() {
  console.log('bye');
}
```

in my html I have actions like such:

```
  <head>
    <script src="./assets/js/myModule.ts" type="module"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span onclick="myModule.hello()">Press to greet</span>
  </body>
...
```

The app has a `server.js` file:

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware").createProxyMiddleware;
const Bundler = require("parcel-bundler");
const express = require("express");

const bundler = new Bundler("index.html");
const app = express();

app.use(
  "/api",
  proxy({
    target: process.env.API_SERVER || "http://localhost:1337/"
  })
);

app.use(bundler.middleware());

app.listen(Number(process.env.PORT || 1234));
```

But everytime I launch the server, I get an error:
`myModule is not defined`

I tried already:

- Using npm link.
- requiring the file in the server.js and passing it with `app.use(myModule.ts)`

Comment: JS modules don't expose their exports to the global (`window`) namespace, so you can't call them from an HTML attribute without more setup. [This question and its two answers explain further.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590393/es6-modules-undefined-onclick-function-after-import)

Answer (score 1):

try define the static file, something like:

app.use(express.static('assets'))

For more details check official docs > https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html.

Comment: I tried this and didn't work :( I have it in a assets/js folder and I added: `app.use(express.static("/assets/js"));`

Comment: you don't need to put "/assets/js" just put "assets", like app.use(express.static('assets'))