# How do I import other modules in a script typescript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, module, script-tag

I am a typescript newbie. I don't know how to reference (import) a module in a script

In my `index.html` file I am referencing

```html
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

and in the `main.ts` file I am trying to import another typescrtipt module

```js
import greet from './greeter';
greet();
```

and in the `greeter.ts` file I am exporting a function

```js
export default function greet(): void {
  console.log('Hello World');
}
```

But in the browser console I see an error that says `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

Here's my `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

I tried changing the `"module"` property to `"es2015"` but it does not work.

Comment: I think you have first to transpile it. Browser (correct me if i am wrong) cant work with typescript.

Comment: I transpiled it. If you look closely you will see that I am linking the transpiled `js` files in my html file

Comment: Have you tried to set the script type to module? `type="module"`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#aside_%E2%80%94_.mjs_versus_.js See last section: "It is also worth noting that:" & https://stackoverflow.com/a/44591205/5781499

Comment: I did not know about it! It does work if you specify `type="module"`. But then any package you install via `npm` or `yarn` can not be imported. It says `Failed to resolve module specifier "<package-name>". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".` in the browser console

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out that I don't need to import that module. I can just add another script tag before the existing script tag which links to the `greeter.js`

```html
<script src="greeter.js"></script>
```

and then I do not need to `export` in `greeter.ts` or import in `main.ts`