# How to execute onsubmit method, after setting the html in body.innerHTML asynchronously

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I fetched a login form asynchronously, and setted it inside `document.body`. I declared it's on submit form before that, and now getting a `Reference error`. Is there any way to set onsubmit using html, without having to call `loginForm.onsubmit = login`. In chrome inspector sources, even after setting `/session` in body, it still shows original `index.html` code.

Bellow you will find `public/js/app.js`

```
const result = await fetch('/session');

if (result) {
    const login = await result.text();
    document.body.innerHTML = login;
}

function login(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const loginForm = document.getElementById('loginForm');
    console.log(loginForm);
    const options = { method: loginForm.method, body: new FormData(loginForm) };
    const loginButton = document.getElementById('loginButton');
    const loginButtonHTML = loginButton.innerHTML;
    loginButton.innerHTML = 'Loading...';
    disableElements(loginForm);
    // const result = await fetch(loginForm.action, options);
}
```

The html returned from `/session` is

```
<form id="loginForm" action="/user/login" method="post" onsubmit="login(event)">
    <input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="current-password" placeholder="Password">
    <button id="loginButton" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

The complete error code is:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: login is not defined at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit ((index):1:1)`

The original html page which includes with the script `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Aveloz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Loading...</h1>
    </div>

<script type="module" src="public/js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're missing the `()` to call the function: `onsubmit="login()"`

Comment: You also need to pass the event argument: `onsubmit="login(event)"`

Comment: @Barmar Shouldn't it be `onsubmit="login(this)"` or `event` is also there?

Comment: Did that, same result

Comment: @n1md7 The function is defined `function login(e)` so it expects the event as the argument, not th eelement.

Comment: @IglesiasLeonardo Please paste the complete error message.

Comment: @Barmar `Uncaught ReferenceError: login is not defined at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit ((index):1:1)`

Comment: Include your script before that html

Comment: Is the function in the original HTML, or in the HTML that you assign from the AJAX call?

Comment: @n1md7 and @Barmar, yes. Maybe because the script type is `module`, but i need it because i'm builing a single page app, and it would be much simpler with modules

Comment: @n1md7 @Barmar, i tried removing `type=module`, that's not the problem

Comment: @GarrGodfrey also did that and error is still there

Comment: `<script>` tag needs to be before the `</body>` end tag not after it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you import the javascript as a module, you need to export the login function:

```
export function login(e) {
...
```

you'd then have to import into you html from something that isn't a module:

```
import { login } from './public/js/app.js';
```

Comment: I would only need to import it, if login function was not in the same `app.js`. But i still tried this, and the result is the same

Comment: but your calling it from your HTML. You need to export and import it into your DOM somewhere.

Comment: I removed `type="module"` to test, and got the same error

Comment: try setting `window.login = login` inside your module.  See
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590393/es6-modules-undefined-onclick-function-after-import

Comment: that is it. Thank you very much

Comment: The best option is still to call `loginForm.onsubmit = login` because `Window` already has its on set of methods, and it would not be good to mess with it