# Simple astro plain javascript function

Tags: javascript, astrojs

I am trying to learn Astro.  I have this simple component and I don't know how to wire in a javascript function.  Here is the code:

```js
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/replacement_timeline", 
                            {headers:{accept: "text/html"}}
                        );
const svgPic = await response.text();
var one_hundred_ar = "xMidYMin slice";
var one_hundred_label = "100%";
export function toggle_100_perc() {
    alert("here")
}
```

```html
<div id="svg-container">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 2000 42000" width="1200" height="500" preserveAspectRatio={one_hundred_ar}>
        <Fragment set:html={svgPic}>
        </Fragment>    
    </svg>
</div>
    <div>
        <input id="scale" type="button" value={one_hundred_label} onclick="toggle_100_perc()">
        <input id="scroll-up" type="button" value="^">
        <input id="scroll-down" type="button" value="v">
    </div>


<style>
    #svg-container {
        border: solid;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 5px
    }
</style>
```

How do I activate the `toggle_100_perc()` function?  I suspect my problem has nothing to do with Astro, rather javascript.

Comment: I think this may bring you an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590393/es6-modules-undefined-onclick-function-after-import