# "Cannot Use import statement outside a module" Error

Tags: javascript, import, module

I don't know how to resolve this error, whether to create a module or something. Require JS won't work since I'm working with a browser. How do I resolve this error with client-based code? Do I need to install packages to resolve it? Please help.

BTW my JS code:

```
import floor from 'mathjs';
import random from 'mathjs';
var colorValue = Array("#000000", "#000000", "#000000");
const hexadecimal = Array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D","E","F");
listening();




function listening() {
    document.getElementById("changeColorOne").addEventListener(click, changeColor1);
    document.getElementById("changeColorTwo").addEventListener(click, changeColor2);
    document.getElementById("changeColorThree").addEventListener(click, changeColor3);
}
function changeColor1() {
    document.querySelector(".square1").style.background = colorValue[0];
    colorValue[0] = colorDecide();
}
function changeColor2() {
    document.querySelector(".square2").style.background = colorValue[1];
    colorValue[1] = colorDecide();
}
function changeColor3(){
    document.querySelector(".square3").style.background = colorValue[2];
    colorValue[2] = colorDecide();
}
function colorDecide() {
    var tempValue = "#";
    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        let x = floor(random() * 16);

        tempValue = tempValue.concat(hexadecimal[x]);
    }
    return tempValue;
}
```

Comment: Add `type="module"` to the script tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 Modules: Undefined onclick function after import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590393/es6-modules-undefined-onclick-function-after-import)

Comment: @konradLinkowski What do you mean by that?

Comment: Show your script tag

Comment: Or is this an error that you're getting in node? In which case see [SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384179/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)

Comment: @konradlinkowski <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use native `import` and `export` statements you have to module system.

```
<script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
```

For more information on [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)`