# problem with displaying data from firebase to a html page

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display data from my database. I'm just learning to work with a database. I don't get anything to show when i press the button. Maybe someone can help me.

My js code is:

```
<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-app.js"></script>

<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-database.js"></script>


<script type="module">
  // ...
    
        // TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
        const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyD2dGlAuA0zPpSGlYkCAFsPM8bsoWaRV44",
        authDomain: "app.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "app",
        storageBucket: "app.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "966901972374",
        appId: "1:966901972374:web:663a1b6fc7324c4021b1b7",
        measurementId: "G-CD22ET3FG6"
        };
    
        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        var db = firebase.firestore();
        
        function readData() {
        var dataContainer = document.getElementById('data-container');
        
        var productsRef = db.collection("products");
        
        productsRef.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        var data = doc.data();
        var item = document.createElement('div');
        item.innerHTML = 'Description: ' + data.description + ', Name: ' + data.name + ', Price: ' + data.price; 
        dataContainer.appendChild(item);
        });
        });
        };
</script>
```

My html code is:

```
<body>
  <div id="data-container"></div>
  <button onclick="readData()">Read Data</button>
</body>
```

I'm getting a error code:
Uncaught ReferenceError: readData is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (profili:82:32)

I also can i screenshot how the database looks in the firebase. Which i have attached.

My database rules are

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I have googled and searched in the stackoverflow but couldn't find what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your `readData` is defined in a module, so you can't just call it from the global namespace. Instead, use `addEventListener` to attach the callback to the HTML dynamically.

For example, if you export the `readData` from your module with:

```
export readData;
```

You can use it in your other code block with

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', readData)
```

Also see: [ES6 Modules: Undefined onclick function after import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590393/es6-modules-undefined-onclick-function-after-import)